# Has DuckDuckGo started ignoring what you search for entirely?

Tags: duckduckgo

Recently, I've found DuckDuckGo to give even worse search results than before. It seems to be entirely ignoring what I quote. For example, the seach query:

```
"PS One" exact release dates
```

URL: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22PS+One%22+exact+release+dates&ia=web

Finds nothing whatsoever related to the release dates for the PS One console from 2000, which was a "slim" remake of the PlayStation from 1994. The webpages don't even contain the string "PS One" at all. And this is just one example of many recently.

Isn't the whole point of quoting a text that you demand that it has to be present? This is infuriating to say the least.

Comment: I don't see a problem here, so it has **not** started to completely ignore the search terms. Maybe are you using Tor Browser, and this changes its behaviour? [See image of Results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFQuN.png)

Comment: This issue can't be reproduced.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22PS+One%22+exact+release+dates&ia=web does indeed return top results that include "PS One" as well as release dates.